# mapbox points on a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I would like to incorporate mapbox into my rails app. Currently I have a list of lat and longitude points that I am pulling from the database. I am able to pull them from the databases and put them in an array, but I cannot get them to show on the map.

Comment: Since you are new, you might want to look up the guides on posting question in SO. You need to be more specific, post your code snippets and tell us exactly where you need help.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the Mapbox.js API... If you are...

You will need to put some javascript on to your web page which will list the points. You can then add the long/lats by calling a method in your code behind. Like so....

```
<link href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>

<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<div id='map' />

<script type='text/javascript'>

    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '[yourmapname]')

    L.mapbox.markerLayer({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
        type: 'MultiPoint',
        coordinates: [ <%=getPins()%> ] 
    },
        properties: {
            title: ['A Pin'],
            description: ['1234'],
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    </script>
```

getPins() calls a function in the code behind which will need return a string formatted like so - "[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...". So if you already have an array, then just format this into a string using that format - and return that.

The line "type: 'Multipoint'," means that the API will read the string that you pass it back and create a pin for each one.